# Error "ISO C forbids forward parameter decleration" when passing a struct pointer to a function?

Tags: c

I have the following code, the struct declaration is before the main, so is the function declaration

```
struct stuff{
        int sale_per_day[Kdays];
        int max_sale;
        };

void set_max();
```

and that part is in the end...

```
void set_max(struct stuff *point; int n = 0)
{
return;
}
```

Now what exactly am I doing wrong? I get the

> "ISO C forbids forward parameter declaration"

error. I am working with GCC C89 as per the course demands.

Comment: I don't think C89 has default argument values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks as if it just needs a comma instead of a semicolon:

```
void set_max(struct stuff *point, int n = 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues with your code snippet:

```
void set_max(struct stuff *point; int n = 0)
```

1) Your prototype does not match the definition.  C usually complains about that
2) You definition contains a semicolon where it should be a comma
3) I don't think `int n = 0` is allowed in the parameter list either.

Please try the following.

```
struct stuff {
    int sale_per_day[Kdays];
    int max_sale;
};

void set_max(struct stuff *point);
```

and

```
void set_max(struct stuff *point)
{
    int n = 0;
    return;
}
```